# Write PHP in HTML file and then convert?

Tags: php, html

I have the following code

server.php:

```
<?php
define("SITE_TITLE", "TheMeister");
if ($_GET['page'] == 'homepage') {
  $page = file_get_contents('template/views/homepage.php');

  print(preg_replace('~\{- (.*?)\ -}~s','$1',$page));
}
?>
```

homepage.php

```
<h1>This izza title</h1>
<p>This is paragraph {-SITE_TITLE-}</p>
```

My idea is to be able to write PHP code directly in an document without using `<?php` directly in the document for easier readability.

Currently the code will output `"This is paragraph SITE_TITLE"`. How can I manage to make it output it as PHP code? Or is there a better approach to convert `{- (text) -}` into PHP code? `"(text)"` may vary from string to functions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use template engines like [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com) , here's an example of twig template:

```
echo $twig->render('index.html', ['foo' => 'bar');
```

then you can use

```
{{ foo }}
```

to print the value `bar` on `index.html` file. there are many other features like loops and if conditions, you can find them by reading the docs [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/)